# Python -m Loading Site Package

Tags: python, setuptools

I have two packages installed via pip which are com.ziath.acacus and com.ziath.driver which install in 'dotted' packages.  If I then write a module that imports these:

```
from com.ziath.acacus.reader import GiSReader
from com.ziath.driver.Zebra2707 import Zebra2707
```

When I execute these using -m : python -m com.ziath.ritrack.manu.RITrackManu -l debug; I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\nbenn\GitHub\RITrackManu\src>python -m com.ziath.ritrack.manu.RITrackManu -l debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\nbenn\GitHub\RITrackManu\src\com\ziath\ritrack\manu\RITrackManu.py", line 8, in <module>
    from com.ziath.acacus.reader import GiSReader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'com.ziath.acacus'
```

However when I execute from the source file : python com\ziath\ritrack\manu\RITrackManu.py -l debug it works with the following:

```
C:\Users\nbenn\GitHub\RITrackManu\src>python com\ziath\ritrack\manu\RITrackManu.py -l debug
RITRack Manu
INFO:root:rfid com port is COM3
INFO:root:linear com port is COM4
```

I'm frankly stumped - the **init**.py file is there on each directory, com/ com/ziath and com/acacus and the setup.py file is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = 'com.ziath.acacus', 
    version ='1.19', 
    packages = ['com.ziath.acacus'],
    package_dir={'':'src'},
    install_requires = ['crcmod', 'pyserial'],
    python_requires='>=3.7'
)
```

The com.ziath.driver package is the same with the name acacus changed to driver.

If anyone has any sugestions I'd be grateful!

Cheers,

Neil

Comment: Does `python -c 'import com.ziath.ritrack.manuRITrackManu; import python.ziath.acacus'` work?  If not -- and the error implies "not" -- what does `python -c 'import sys; print(repr(sys.path))'` emit? (Might also drop to the debugger when the problem hits and check that `sys.path` hasn't been changed at runtime from its initial state).

Comment: python -c "import com.ziath.driver; import com.ziath.acacus" works without error

Comment: sys.path includes site-packagespython -c "import sys; print(repr(sys.path))"
['', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\python311.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\Lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\nbenn\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python311\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages']

Comment: putting the print from syspath gives: the path (including 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages') but still ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'com.ziath.acacus'.  When run without -m the path is the same except that tee path where the .py file being executed is located

Comment: It's hard to tell from the comments above -- is either of those sys.path prints done _from the debugger_ after the failure? (That is, use `python -i -m com.ziath.ritrack.manu.RITrackManu`, then when it fails, `import pdb; pdb.pm()`, and then `print(sys.argv)` from there).

Comment: Sorry you are correct - no I just included that command at the top of the python code file.  I'll try in the interpreter on Monday.

Comment: Backing up here -- you mention `Python311\Lib\site-packages` as the location you expect `com.ziath.acacus` to come from, but you have a `com.ziath.ritrack` in your working tree. If you have two different `com.ziath` packages in two different locations, they need to be specially written to merge their contents, with a technique called "namespace packages"; see https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/